# Jedi fails to start Jedi EPC Server because python 3.8 is installed and 3.7 not

Tags: python, jedi

Is the only solution to downgrade python 3.8 to 3.7 or wait till it is supported? Or are there other options? The error message is this:

> Error (jedi):
> ================================ Failed to start Jedi EPC server. ================================
>
> *** EPC Error *** Server may raise an error. Use "M-x epc:pop-to-last-server-process-buffer RET" to see full traceback:
> /home/user/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/python: error
> while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Process epc:server:2 exited abnormally with code 127
>
> *** EPC Server Config *** Server arguments: ("/home/user/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver")
> Actual command:
> /home/user/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/bin/jediepcserver
> VIRTUAL_ENV envvar: nil
>
> *** jedi-mode is disabled in # *** Fix the problem and re-enable it.
>
> *** You may need to run "M-x jedi:install-server". *** This could solve the problem especially if you haven't run the command yet since
> Jedi.el installation or update and if the server complains about
> Python module imports.

`jedi:install-server` returns similar error message, just like `epc:pop-to-last-server-process-buffer`.

Comment: Well I looked it up and there is actually no file named "libpython3.7m.so.1.0". Should I add it manually?